# Store string into int[] array

Tags: java

I have a string `String strings ="100.122.323.344;543.433.872.438;218.544.678.322";`
I want to store into int[] like this `int[] ={{100,122,323,344},{543,433,872,438},{218,544,678,322}}`
Below is the sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String strings = "100.122.323.344;543.433.872.438;218.544.678.322";
    strings = strings.replace(".", ",");
    System.out.println(strings);
    String[] coordinates = strings.split(";");
    String[] rect=null;
    int[] intcoordinates;
    for(int i=0;i<coordinates.length;i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(coordinates[i]);
        rect= coordinates[i].split(",");

        for(int j=0;j<rect.length;j++)
        {



        }

    }

}
```

Till now i am able to separate value from string but don't know how to convert to int please help

Comment: Use Integer.parseInt()

Comment: so the problem is only _"how to convert string to int"_? which you can simply [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+convert+string+to+int&oq=how+to+convert+string+to+int) and get a thousand of answer?

Comment: Why do you replace every period with a comma? Looks very unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to store the value as int, you should know the `{{100,122,323,344},{543,433,872,438},{218,544,678,322}}` is a two dimensional array, so it's `int[][]`. Then the array must be init, the row and col can be figured out .

```
    int[][] intcoordinates = new int[3][4]; // init the array, the row and the col can be figured.
    for(int i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(coordinates[i]);
        rect = coordinates[i].split(",");
        for(int j=0; j<rect.length; j++)
        {
            intcoordinates[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(rect[j]);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(intcoordinates));
```

The final execution is `[[100, 122, 323, 344], [543, 433, 872, 438], [218, 544, 678, 322]]`. To get the output `{{100,122,323,344},{543,433,872,438},{218,544,678,322}}`, you must make some additional methods. So if you just want to get the output, i'd say just replace the `.` to `,`, `;` to `},{`, and add the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
int intrect = Integer.parseInt(rect[j]);
```

to convert your rect[j] to int.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String strings = "100.122.323.344;543.433.872.438;218.544.678.322";
    strings = strings.replace(".", ",");
    System.out.println(strings);
    String[] coordinates = strings.split(";");
    String[] rect = null;
    int[][] intcoordinates = new int[3][4];  // initialize the size of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        // System.out.println(coordinates[i]);
        rect = coordinates[i].split(",");        
        for (int j = 0; j < rect.length; j++) {
            intcoordinates[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(rect[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

intcoordinates contains [[100, 122, 323, 344], [543, 433, 872, 438], [218, 544, 678, 322]] at the end of the execution. This is the final result of the conversion.

Comment: But how to get output as i am expecting int[] ={{100,122,323,344},{543,433,872,438},{218,544,678,322}}

Comment: intcoordinates should be a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: intcoordinates equals [[100, 122, 323, 344], [543, 433, 872, 438], [218, 544, 678, 322]] at the end of the execution. This is the array you want.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a two dimentional array `intcoordinates` with rows and cols. If don't know the row size, than you should count maximum row size. Than convert `String` to `int` and assign to this array.

```
 int[][] intcoordinates=new int[coordinates.length][countMaxRow(coordinates)];
 for(int i=0;i<coordinates.length;i++){
    rect= coordinates[i].split(",");
    for(int j=0;j<rect.length;j++){
       intcoordinates[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(rect[j]);
    }
 }
 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(intcoordinates));
```

Here is maximum row count method

```
static int countMaxRow(String[] arr){
    int max=0;
    for (String str : arr) {
        String a[]=str.split(",");
        if(max< a.length){
            max= a.length;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually Scanner and collections should work for you:

```
        String strings = "100.122.323.344;543.433.872.438;218.544.678.322";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(strings.getBytes()));
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(scanner.next().getBytes()));
        scanner2.useDelimiter("\\D");
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        while(scanner2.hasNextInt())
            lst.add(scanner2.nextInt());
        list.add(lst);  
    }
    System.out.println("Lists: ");
    for(List<Integer> lst : list)
        System.out.println(lst);
```